# General derivative of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, solution-verification

Is the following correct?

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k-n+1)} a_k x^{k-n} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Obviously this encounters $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-n)}$ which should be zero for the formula to work and indeed

$$\lim \limits_{x \to n} \frac{1}{\Gamma (1-n)} = 0$$

but is this enough to make the formula rigorous or are there other flaws?

Comment: Why are you using the Gamma function and not the factorial?

Comment: @vitamind because $(k-n+1)$ can get negative

Comment: If thats the case the summand is $0$, since $\lvert\Gamma(-n)\rvert\to\infty,n\in\mathbb{N}$. I don't think that your formula has flaws though.

Answer (score 3):

The *[gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)* has poles at zero and the negative integers and $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$ is an entire function with zeros at these points. This makes the representation below valid.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k-n+1)} a_k x^{k-n} \quad m, n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

> Nevertheless we can do the same job with simpler means, since we have for $m,n$ non-negative integers:
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k&=\sum_{k=0}^ma_k\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^ma_k \color{blue}{k^{\underline{n}}}x^{k-n}
> \end{align*}
> where $k^{\underline{n}}=k(k-1)\cdots (k-n+1)$ denotes the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct. If you only want to use the classic factorial function, you may write the formula is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k = 
\sum_{k=0}^m \Theta(k-n) a_k \frac{k!}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N},$$
where $\Theta$ is the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). It is an (easy) function that returns $0$ or $1$. I modified the input in the formula, so that it gives us the values that we need.